# How to block web access in Excel?

Tags: excel, ms-office

I blocked certain websites from my browser but can access them through Microsoft Excel. You go to the data tab and click on From The Web and you can access the internet.

I tried to find ways to prevent web access in Excel but I can't find them. Is there anyway to disable web in Excel or Microsoft office in general?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.